# How to disable checking for WWW-Authenticate header on 401 in HttpUrlConnection on Android?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm working with a web service that returns 401 when my auth cookie expires, which causes HttpUrlConnection to throw this error:

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
    at ...
```

I know this is happening because the server isn't returning a WWW-Authenticate header, but that's out of my control. It's nice that HttpUrlConnection does this checking for me, but this is the real world and we don't always get to work with servers that perfectly follow the HTTP spec. I can't move away from HttpUrlConnection because of other code dependencies, so how do I disable the check so I can actually make use of the response?

Comment: Could you paste your code so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have same issue with this, when i get 401 I expect json result even if its 401 but in this case it throws IOException when I start reading input stream.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and catch the error.

```
try{
     //code that causes error
}
catch(IOException ex){
    if(ex.getMessage().equals("No authentication challenges found")){
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this as a temporary hack, but it seems really fragile, and couldn't I theoretically get the same exception for a 403?

Comment: you can use the getResponseCode() function of HttpURLConnection to determine the response code if you need to differentiate the response code.

Comment: I actually can't, as that's the method that throws the exception under these circumstances. I suppose that will learn me to snip stack traces so far up...